Exception to L'Hôpital's Rule
My teacher taught that L'Hôpital's Rule can be used to evaluate limits when both the numerator and the denominator tend to zero or infinity, but there is one exception:
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x+\sin x}{x}=1$$
Since $\sin x$ is a bounded function but $x$ is not, so as $x\to \infty$, the numerator's value approaches the denominator. But, if we apply L'Hôpital's Rule,
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x+\sin x}{x}=\lim_{x\to \infty}1+\cos x=D.N.E.$$
which does not exist as $\cos x$ does not approach a particular value but rather oscillates in $(-1,1)$ as $x\to \infty$. Why is there in a fallacy in using L'Hôpital's Rule for this limit? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Check your notes; they should say that one of the conditions for the rule to be applicable is that the limit $\lim_{x \to a} f'(x) / g'(x)$ exists. If not, then it's probably your teacher's fault.

see this for example

It is necessary for L'Hospital's Rule to work, that the limit of the quotient with the derivatives exists. If not, the rule fails.
This limit though, can be solved simply:
$\lim_\limits{x \rightarrow \infty} (\dfrac{x + \sin x}{x}) =\lim_\limits{x \rightarrow \infty} (1 + \dfrac{\sin x}{x}) = 1 $. And $\lim_\limits{x \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{\sin x}{x}=0$ by the squeeze theorem.
